# Binding to separate element on (click) in Angular 2

Tags: html, audio, angular

I have an html audio element that I would like to play when you click an image of a play button. I'm working in Angular 2 so it's a little more complicated than just using jQuery binding... Here's what I have so far:

```
@Component({
selector: 'listen',
template: `
    <h1>Play Your Greeting!</h1>

    <img src="../images/play.svg" (click)="playMusic($event)"> 
    <audio controls src="../music/06 What Is The Light_.mp3">
`,
styles: [`
        img {
            width: 30%;
        }
`]
})
export class ListenComponent {


constructor(
    private listenService: ListenService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
    ) {}

playMusic(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    event.target.play();
}
}
```

Obviously the event is attaching to the image, but somehow I need the .play() to be called on the audio tag.

Comment: The document object is still available, you might want to try `document.getElementById("tagID").play();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign a local variable to the `audio` element, then pass it to the method call

```
<img src="../images/play.svg" (click)="playMusic(audioEl)"> 
<audio #audioEl controls src="../music/06 What Is The Light_.mp3">

playMusic(el: HTMLAudioElement) {
  el.play();
}
```

See the `#audioEl`. This is assigning the `audio` element to the template accessible variable. You can see it is being passed to the `playMusic` method call